# Could anyone give an explain on following javascript RE code?

Tags: javascript, regex

Could anyone give an explain on following example code?
it's from the last example [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).

Not sure why there's no `'\'` before the `'.'` , it can get same result by adding `'\'`.

JavaScript:

```
var url = "http://xxx.domain.com";
print(/[^.]+/.exec(url)[0].substr(7)); // prints "xxx"
```

Comment: [MDN can](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) the character class [^something] means anything BUT something where something in this case is a full stop, not a regex special char

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note the paragraph [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) regarding *Metacharacters Inside Character Classes*

> Note that the only special characters or metacharacters inside a character class are the closing bracket (]), the backslash (\), the caret (^) and the hyphen (-). The usual metacharacters are normal characters inside a character class, and do not need to be escaped by a backslash.

Comment: An additional note is that the hyphen doesn't need to be escaped at the start or end of the group, and in cases where it doesn't make sense, like after a `x-y` in a character class.  The caret only needs to be escaped at the start of a group.  For example `[0-3-9]` would match 0, 1, 2, 3, 9, or a hyphen, and `[a^]` would match a or a caret.

Answer (score 5):

Get the chars up to the first period, then remove the first 7 which is the http:// so that leaves you with the first part of the domain which in this case is `xxx`.

`[^.]+` means one or more characters that is not a period so this matches `http://xxx`.  Noe that the period does not need to be escaped inside the brackets to be treated as a normal character as it has no special meaning inside the brackets.

`[0]` means the entire match which is `http://xxx`

`.substr(7)` means to get the characters after the first 7 which will be `xxx`

Comment: (+1) but `[0]` doesn't mean the first match, it means the entire match.  `[1]` doesn't mean the second match, it means the second capture group.

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand +1 though a small fix... the second array element from `exec()` (`[1]`) would be the first capture group, not the second.

Comment: Fixed the comment about `[0]`.

Comment: My concern is why used `[^.]` but not `[^\.]` ,since the `.` should be a special chars in RegExp, it's a special case for `[^]` ? or could any one give me some official document link on it ?

Comment: @VincentHou - A `.` is not a special character inside of `[^.]` so it does not need to be escaped inside the brackets.  If that was really your original question, then you should have specified that in the original question.